# Get average value

Tags: php, sql

I am doing a query that brings the average values, as long as the distance is up to 90km:

```
SELECT avg(price),(6371 * acos(
 cos( radians(-23.2632227) )
 * cos( radians( lat ) )
 * cos( radians( lng ) - radians(-45.9414303) )
 + sin( radians(-23.2632227) )
 * sin( radians( lat ) ) 
 )
) AS distance
FROM fcs_workers
HAVING distance < 90
```

The problem is that when I put the avg(price) it calculates the average of all the registers, including those that are in a greater distance. Without the avg (price) it brings right only those that are within the distance of 100km
Without avg(price):

```
distance
78.82683615218286
6.351835016010867
```

with avg(price)

```
avg(price)       |distance
76.66666666666667|78.82683615218286
```

I'd like to have the average price, like: 110

The table:

```
id | name|price|lat        |lng
1  |joana|100  |-23.542746 |-46.651302
2  |maria|120  |-23.241726 |-45.883827
3  |lucia|40   |-22.8117593|-45.1786567
```

Obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

Use a subquery:

```
SELECT avg(price),
FROM (SELECT w.*,
             (6371 * acos(
 cos( radians(-23.2632227) )
 * cos( radians( lat ) )
 * cos( radians( lng ) - radians(-45.9414303) )
 + sin( radians(-23.2632227) )
 * sin( radians( lat ) ) 
 )
             ) AS distance
      FROM fcs_workers
     ) w
WHERE distance < 90;
```

Actually, you can also keep the `HAVING` in the subquery . . . there is probably a bit of a performance gain because it reduces the size of the intermediate table.